# jQuery UI Autocomplete displaying wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ72p/2/) for the interactive example

I have an auto-complete box similar to the example.  If you start typing a name, that begins with `M` it will give you a drop-down list.  If arrow down through the names (rather than selecting one with your mouse), you will notice, that the input box gets filled with the value rather than the name of the person.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type M...">
<input type="hidden" id="myHidden">
```

Script:

```
$("#myInput").autocomplete({
    delay: 500,

    minLength: 1,

    select: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#myHidden").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },

    source: [{"label":"Marie","value":1},
             {"label":"Michelle","value":2},
             {"label":"Mia","value":3},
             {"label":"Melissa","value":4},
             // ...etc
    ];
});
```

When you select a name, it adds it to the input correctly, but I'm trying to get rid of the numerical values being displayed as you arrow through the choices.

I didn't see any event in the [auto-complete docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to hook into accomplish this.

May I have missed it or perhaps there is a way of restructuring my source data to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

```
$("#myInput").autocomplete({
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#myHidden").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    source: [{"label":"Marie","value":1},
             {"label":"Michelle","value":2},
             //...
             {"label":"Maureen","value":40}]
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ72p/43/)

Comment: Ah curses, I glossed over focus thinking it was the event for when the input gained focus.  Thanks!